# C++ - Using codeblock to read ip adress from a file

Tags: c++, ip

I've been trying to take out ip adress from a file, as well as few other parameters. In the beggining i would like to mention that i have less than 10 points, and im not able to upload images - that's why i will provide links to the pictures.

Here is screenshot of a configuration file that i read from:
https://pasteboard.co/IpyYdxd.png

My code, takes the port, datagram_size and transmission_speed as int variable and there is no problem with using them with my udp socket implementation. However, it won't let me use my GROUP variable which is std::basic_string type because it needs const char* variable.

Here is view of my console application:
https://pasteboard.co/Ipza3hON.png

I've tried to convert strings / ints to constant char with value.c_str() function, however something is wrong.

```
// FILE TO BE SEND
FILE *file_handler; 
if((file_handler = fopen("output_file.dat", "rb")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Error: unable to read file\n");
    exit(-1);
}


char buf[DATAGRAM_SIZE];
int i = 0;
// CONFIGURATION FILE
std::ifstream cFile ("plik_konfiguracyjny.txt"); 
if (cFile.is_open()){
    std::string line;
    set_light_red // set color to light red
    while(getline(cFile, line)){
        line.erase(std::remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), isspace),line.end());

    if(line[0] == '#' || line.empty()){ // if line starts with # or is empty - ignore
        continue;
    }

        auto delimiterPos = line.find("=");
        auto name = line.substr(0, delimiterPos);
        auto value = line.substr(delimiterPos + 1);
        printf(value.c_str()); // display received value from current line
        printf("\n");

    printf("zmienna i: %i\n",i); // display i to check what's the value in current loop

    if(i == 0){
    group = value.c_str(); // CONVERT STRING TO CONST CHAR*
    }
    if(i == 1){
    port = std::stoi(value);
    }
    if(i == 2){
    DATAGRAM_SIZE = std::stoi(value);
    }
    if(i == 3){
    wait_for = std::stoi(value);
    }

    i = i +1;

    }

    set_white
    printf("PARAMETRY TRANSMISJI ");
    set_green
    printf("ZALADOWANE\n\n");
    set_white
}
else {

    printf("PARAMETRY TRANSMISJI ");
    set_red
    printf("NIEZALADOWANE\n\n");
    set_white
}

// create UDP with parameters from file
memset((char *) &addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(group);
addr.sin_port = htons(port);
```

There are no errors, and it compile fine, however it won't use ip adress in the given file.

here is what i mean shown with picture (and great paint skills)
https://pasteboard.co/IpzacMF.png

Comment: First of all please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then don't post images of text, copy-paste the text *as text* into the question to make it self-contained. Lastly, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: And on an unrelated note, don't use index numbers to detect what kind of data you have in your configuration file. If you do, the configuration file *always* needs to have its records in a specific order. Instead have the `name` of the configuration, use it to decide what the value is for.

Comment: Remember that questions and answers on this site isn't only for you, they are for *everyone* who have the same or similar problems, now or in the future. Now think about what happens if the links you have in your question disappears, or the contents are changed to something else. That will make the question worthless for everyone in the future. That's why you should read the links provided in my first comment, so you learn how to write better questions in the future (and how to improve this one).

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell what `group` is. It could be a `char *`, it could be a `std::string`, it could be something else.

But your comment suggests that `group` is of type `const char *`. If this is correct, then `group = value.c_str();` doesn't make any sense. Why set `group` to point to a buffer whose contents is constantly changing? Yes, it contains the host right this second, but it's about to get overwritten by the next iteration of the loop. Why stash a pointer to it?

What if the contents of `value` grows in size in the next iteration of the loop and the internal implementation of `std::string` frees the existing buffer and allocates a new, larger one? Now, `group` is pointing to a buffer that's no longer even allocated!

Don't store the return value from `c_str` and try to access it after you've modified the string.